# Why doesn't lithium form dilithium crystals? (Calling Mr.Spock)

Tags: bond, alkali-metals

Hydrogen is in the first column of the periodic table. At STP it is a diatomic gas. When cooled and/or under pressure it forms a crystalline solid of di-hydrogen molecules. Calculations indicate that under high enough pressure it may form a monatomic basis metallic crystal, and scientists are actively looking to find evidence of this. Results so far seem inconclusive.

However, lithium is also a first column element. But its solid is a monoatomic basis metal and NOT a dilithium crystal as we would expect based on hydrogen. Why not?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70678/do-li4-or-li8-molecules-exist https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/91279/do-alkali-metals-not-form-diatomic-molecules

Comment: Happy to!  Any advice on what is not specific?  I expect solid lithium to look like solid hydrogen.  Solid hydrogen is a lattice of diatomic molecules, but lithium is a metal with a single atom basis.  Does this wording work better?

Comment: @PaulYoung No because all the links suggested do answer the question.

Comment: As far as molecular structure goes H2 is better compared with halides - single bond completes el. shell.

Comment: I do think Mithoron's second link answer the Q, as well as his comment